# Select first and last three strings from column for conditionSQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, substring

My goal is to select all the columns that start and end with the same 3 strings as the first row.
In this case it was simple, since the CONCAT was equal to 'SCLMIA'

```
AND CONCAT(origin, destination) = 'SCLMIA' 
AND ((flight_path LIKE '%SCL%' AND flight_path LIKE '%MIA%')
```

but now the difficulty is for multiple strings.

```
AND CONCAT(origin, destination) IN ('SCLMIA', 'SCLIQQ','SCLMAD', 'LIMCUZ', 'BOGMDE', 'FORGRU', 'SDUCGH', 'SCLGRU', 'BOGLIM', 'GYEUIO')
AND (**here I need to replicate the same as above.**)
```

I read that it can be with the functions `SUBSTRING, LEFT AND RIGHT` selecting the three first and last strings but I don't know how to do it.

Tried with this, but failed:
`AND (flight_path LIKE '%' + SUBSTR(flight_path,3, LENGTH(flight_path) - 4) + '%')`

It should be noted that it is a chain of conditions that's why start with AND.

**Edit:**

[Image: Sample of data single path 'SCLMIA'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voaP3.png)
It's from Bigquery.

Comment: Can you include some sample data an output of what you're looking for?

Comment: Is it mysql or bigquery? you tag the both.

Comment: Do not use CONCAT, test separate airports codes.

Comment: @DonkeyKongII I add an example image with the columns affected.

Comment: @KotaMori Bigquery! sorry.

Comment: @Akina there are already separate, but i worked togheter

Comment: *there are already separate, but i worked togheter* Using CONCAT you make undex usage impossible which degrades your query performance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    flight_paths
WHERE 
    CONCAT(origin, destination) IN ('SCLMIA', 'SCLIQQ', 'SCLMAD', 'LIMCUZ',  'BOGMDE', 'FORGRU', 'SDUCGH', 'SCLGRU', 'BOGLIM', 'GYEUIO')
    AND RIGHT(flight_path, 3) = origin 
    AND LEFT(flight_path, 3) = destination
```

Here's a db-fiddle that demonstrates the answer:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vUZ4HL4NC9xaBBZpwTYNcR/0